# "Property does not exist on type" while using custom hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've declared a custom hook

```js
type ControlContextProps =
  | {
      name: string | undefined;
      id: string | undefined;
      selectedOptions: String[] | undefined;
      onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    }
  | {};

const FormControlContext = React.createContext<ControlContextProps>({});

const useFormControl = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(FormControlContext);
  return context;
};
```

When using it, accessing the fields described in `ControlContextProps` results in the typescript error "Property 'xxx' does not exist on type 'ControlContextProps'.ts(2339)". This occurs for any field.

```js
  const { id, name, selectedOptions, onChange } = useFormControl();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Test it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-smoke-m2tdfk?file=/src/App.tsx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `{}` has no properties

You wanted to do something like:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

type ControlContextProps = {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  selectedOptions: String[];
  onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
};

const FormControlContext = createContext<ControlContextProps | undefined>(
  undefined
);

const useFormControl = () => {
  const context = useContext(FormControlContext);
  if (!context) throw new Error("Context have to be used within the provider");
  return context;
};

export default function App() {
  const { id, name, selectedOptions, onChange } = useFormControl();
  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed what I want, cheers!

Nice touch with the Error throw. Thanks. Will mark it as correct asap.

Answer (score 1):

Make the type values optional rather than having `{}`

```
type ControlContextProps =
   {
      name?: string | undefined;
      id?: string | undefined;
      selectedOptions?: String[] | undefined;
      onChange?: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
    }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-pascal-ig6kwh)